# Dropdown menu not filling when setting up form for editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been looking at filling out a form with previous information using javascript, and am able to get the textboxes filled, but the dropdown selections are causing issues. I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856000/dropdown-list-selectedindex-is-not-working-with-getelementbyid-in-javascript) method of selecting a specific option, but it doesn't seem to work with the rest of my code. It works only if I create a separate page without the for loop to fill out the textboxes. I've checked the names and id's  of the selections to see if there was an overlap somewhere else in my code, but that does not appear to be the case. I originally thought that I solved the issue because I misunderstood the difference between the value of the option versus the index of the option. But that changed nothing. I've been using console.log to verify that each step is being called, and that each input is appropriate. I've tried commenting out the code and just setting the element statically.

The issue I'm having is that the drop down boxes don't populate when I select a profile to edit. The textboxes fill with the last saved data, but nothing appears in the dropdowns. What would cause a dropdown to not populate?

This is the html:

```
<!-- Edit Button to edit a profile -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit Profile</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="get" name="editprofiledata" id="editprofiledata">
        <div >
          <label>Details</label>

          <table  id="tableID" class="table table-bordered table-hover tablewithtooltip">
            <thead>
              <tr style="background-color: #787878 ">
                <th>Attribute</th>
                <th>Value</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr><td>Profile Name</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="selectedProfileName" id="selectedProfileName"/></td></tr>
              <tr><td>Profile Mnemonic</td><td><input type="text" value="" name="profileMnemonic" id="profileMnemonic"/></td></tr>
              <tr><td>Tx Data Rate</td><td><select name="txDataRate" id="txDataRate"><option value="1">64  kbps 1/9</option>
                    <option value="2">128 kbps 2/9</option>
                    <option value="3">256 kbps 1/9</option>
                    <option value="6">256 kbps 2/9</option>
                    <option value="5">512 kbps 2/9</option>
                    <option value="4">512 kbps 1/9</option></select></td></tr>
              <tr><td>Rx Data Rate</td><td><select name="rxDataRate" id="rxDataRate"><option value="1">64  kbps 1/9</option>
                   <option value="2">128 kbps 2/9</option>
                   <option value="3">256 kbps 1/9</option>
                   <option value="6">256 kbps 2/9</option>
                   <option value="5">512 kbps 2/9</option>
                   <option value="4">512 kbps 1/9</option></td></tr>    
            </tbody>
      </table>
       </div>
      </form>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" name="updateProfile" id="updateProfile" onclick="saveUpdatedProfile()">Save</button>
     </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

And this is the javascript:

```
function editProfile(){
 $('#editModal').modal();

 var attributeList1 = ["selectedProfileName","profileMnemonic", "txDataRate", "rxDataRate", ... more attributes ...];

 for(var i=0;i<attributeList1.length;i++)

  {

  attr1=attributeList1[i];

  if (attr1 == "txDataRate" || attr1 == "rxDataRate"){

    if (profileData[attr1]==1){
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=0;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==2){
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=1;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==3){
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=2;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==6){
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=3;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==5){
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=4;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=5;
    }
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById(attr1).value=profileData[attr1];
      }
  }
 }
```

Edited to add: I have tried `$('#'+attr1+' option:[value='+profileData[attr1]+']').prop('selected',true);` to select the correct dropdown option with no change.
(Found that suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314636/how-do-you-select-a-particular-option-in-a-select-element-in-jquery))

[Screenshot of problem showing the filled textboxes and empty dropdowns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFjPX.jpg)

SOLVED! Another function was overwriting the html ID's and thus my if/for statements were not able to change the selected dropdown ID.

Comment: I don't see where your JS function editProfile() gets called in the html?

Comment: It's called much earlier on in the html by a button. Essentially, the user selects a profile, and then hits the "edit" button which calls the JS function. That part all works just fine.

Comment: Ok, the first line in your editProfile() functions uses JQuery selector function while else where you use regular JS 'getElementById' selector. Can you change all that to JQuery $ selector and see if it works?

Comment: Okay, using `$("#"+attr1).val(profileData[attr1])` I get the same output with the textboxes being filled with the appropriate data, but the drop down menus being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you if statements working correctly. I mean do you reach to the statement `document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=1;`. One thing I'll do is to put `console.log('selecting 1st index');` and make sure that I get into the if statements, something like this:

```
if (profileData[attr1]==1){
    console.log('selecting 1st index');
    document.getElementById(attr1).selectedIndex=0;
}
```

Also, where your `profileData` are being populated?

Comment: Yes, my if statements are working correctly. Console.log shows that it is going to the correct location.

Comment: My profileData is being populated by another function called loadData(), and this works for everything else that requires the profile information. It also populates the text fields fine, just not the dropdowns.

Comment: I think the issue is not in the code we are seeing. I see you are putting your html in a model. When you run it in the browser, check the source from the browser and make sure you don't have duplicate IDs, also check if it is not a browser specific issue. 
Is there a way you can post a working example? something minimal that we can recreate locally since your code seems fine to us.

Comment: I agree with that assessment. I've narrowed down the potential issue to this function: 

`function loadData(){
  url1 = "/rest/get/configProfileInfo/"+radioNumber;
  

  $.getJSON( url1, function( data ) {

   

   $.each( data, function( key, val ) {



     // store for later user

            profileData[key]=val;



     $('#'+key).html(": "+val);

   

   });

  });

}`

Comment: What is this line for: `$('#' + key).html(": " + val);`

Comment: Thank you! That line was used on the index.html page and is a remnant which is not needed on the manage profiles page. :D

Comment: If I were in your situation, I'll try to run this code `document.getElementById("rxDataRate").selectedIndex=3;` in the console of the browser and see if it will changed the selected value.
If it didn't work, then maybe your id is changed somehow or you have duplicate. 

Can you right click on the select box and choose "Inspect Element" and post a screen shoot of your source for that element?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex = 5;
```

EDIT*

I made the edits below and called the function from the firebug console with your markup and it selected the options. After this I'm out of ideas. Sorry if it doesn't help and good luck with the fix!

```
  function editProfile(){


 var attributeList1 = ["selectedProfileName","profileMnemonic", "txDataRate", "rxDataRate"],
     profileData = {"rxDataRate":3,"txDataRate":5,"selectedProfileName":"abcd","profileMnemonic":"efgh"};

 for(var i=0;i<attributeList1.length;i++){

  attr1=attributeList1[i];

  if (attr1 == "txDataRate" || attr1 == "rxDataRate"){

    if (profileData[attr1]==1){
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=0;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==2){
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=1;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==3){
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=2;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==6){
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=3;
    }
    else if (profileData[attr1]==5){
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=4;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(attr1).options.selectedIndex=5;
    }
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById(attr1).value=profileData[attr1];
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: That does not appear to do anything, either.

Answer (score 0):

I manually populated your array "profileData" to test the code and it does seem to work. So the problem could be your profileData array being empty when your function runs

```
function testDropDownAutoFill(){
 //$('#editModal').modal();
 var attributeList1 = ["selectedProfileName","profileMnemonic", "txDataRate", "rxDataRate"];   
    var profileData = {
        "txDataRate" : Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
        "rxDataRate" : Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1,
    }  
    //console.log(profileData["txDataRate"] +" & " + profileData["rxDataRate"]);
 for(var i=0;i<attributeList1.length;i++)
  {
      var attr1=attributeList1[i];
      if (attr1 == "txDataRate" || attr1 == "rxDataRate"){     
          $("#"+attr1).val(profileData[attr1]);
      }      
  }
 }
```

See JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/angrybird/qvqmL8tv/

Comment: It's not empty. It contains [
 
profileMnemonic
 "This is a test profile"
 
rxDataRate
 "1"
 
selectedProfileName
 "Profile C"
 
selectedSatellite
 "Satellite 1"
 
txDataRate
 "6"
 
]